# How to change layout from table to divs with proper widths and heights?

Tags: html, layout, width, css-tables

I was introduced to HTML about 10 years ago but barely used it again until about a month ago. It turns out I'm supposed to do everything differently now (or did everything wrong without knowing before), and I'm trying to stick to the standards, but some things are troubling me a lot.

I've been hearing a lot of people bashing the usage of tables for layout for example. I don't really know why (are tables really so bad?), but still I've tried to use divs instead and just can't seem to make them work properly. I have isolated my problems into a quite illustrative one, that involves some things I haven't been able to do with divs (and some that I couldn't even do with tables actually).

Here's the problem:

[image: My output]

I've tried many things, and I unfortunately can't even summarize them here cause I don't remember, but here's the code with my attempts to make it work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>Tests</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {height:100%;}
#container
{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:680px;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#column_left
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#column_middle
{
    float: left;
    width: 49.2%;/*59.601562%*/
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#column_right
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
.pad 
{
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 2px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;">
<div id="container">
    <div id="column_left">
        <div class="pad">
            Left Column Top<br/>
            <br/>
            Div only as long as content.<br/>
        </div>
        <div class="pad">
            Left Column Bottom<br/><br/>
            I want this DIV to stretch all the way down to the bottom of the container regardless of the lenght of the content.
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column_middle">
        <div class="pad">
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
            <p>Long Middle Content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="column_right">
        <div class="pad">
            Right content<br/><br/>
            I want this DIV to stretch all the way down to the bottom of the container regardless of the lenght of the content.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Besides the main question, if you pay attention to the width of the middle column, it's not 50. I tried 50% at first, of course, to sum up 100%, but for some crazy reason everything is messed up:

[image: Distorted layout]

Anybody knows why?

Another thing I can't do with tables and don't even know if it's possible at all: I wanted the whole layout to be symmetrical. That is, I would like the longer side-content to determine the width of its div, and also of the other div, while the middle div stretches to fit 100% of the page. Anybody knows if it's possible? Not sure if I'd really use it in my final layout, but it's puzzling me.

Sorry if the question is stupid and turns out to be easy to solve. Like I said, I'm new to proper html/css. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so figured part of it.  Your borders were in addition to the specified widths in some of the browsers.  By dropping your middle div to 49% it fixed the right div being pushed underneath in IE8/IE7/FF4.  Here is it in action:  [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k2vEb/2/)

Answer (score 0):

**Increased the width of container from 680 to 750 it is working....**